# Prototype issue - How do I check for links on an input field and check for the length of that input field?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I sort of started coding for this. It's almost working.
My goals:
1) Check for the length or url's entered in a field (the total length) and reduce each link's length by 20 if the length is greater than 20
2) Determine the characters left in an input field

The javascript in profile.js (prototype):

```
function checkurl_total_length(text) {
    var text = "";
    var matches = [];
    var total_length = 0;
    var urlRegex =  /(http|https):\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\.-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{3}/;

    text.scan(urlRegex, function(match){ matches.push(match[0])});
    for (var index = 0; index < matches.length; ++index) {
        item = matches[index];
        reduce_length = matches.length*20;
        if(item.length>20) {
            total_length = total_length + item.length - reduce_length;
        }
        else {
            total_length = total_length + item.length;
        }


    }

    return total_length;
}

function count_characters(field){
   var limitNum=140;
    var link_length = 0;
   if(checkurl_total_length(field.value)!=0) {
      link_length =link_length+ checkurl_total_length(field.value);
    }
    else {
      link_length = 0;
   }
     limitNum = limitNum+link_length;

    if( link_length !=0 ){
     $("links").update("with links");

    }
    left = limitNum-field.value.length;

    $("count").update(left);

}
```

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"><head>


<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JUST A TEST FILE</title>
<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="profile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head><body>
<h1>
CHARACTERS COUNT
</h1>
<div class="container_24">
    <h2 id="title2">
        TESTING
    </h2>
    <div class="grid_24">

        <div id="count"></div>
         <br /s>

        <div id="links"></div>
   <form >

    <textarea wrap="hard" onpaste="count_characters(this);" onkeyup="count_characters(this);" onkeydown="count_characters(this);"  id="updates" onfocus="count_characters(this);" name="test"/> </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value=" " name="commit" disabled=""/>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- end .container_24 -->
</body></html>
```

Counting characters left is working but checking for url and the length of the url isn't. Any hints on why this isn't working?

Comment: I updated the code based on comment below. I still haven't fixed the issue.

Comment: Ok based on my tests the regular expression is wrong:     var urlRegex =  /(http|https):\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\.-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{3}/; seems to only recognize a few url's. Any help with Regex?

Comment: This seems to work: /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but should this be

```
checkurl_total_length(field.value!=0)   // ) != 0
```